# RubyOnRails Error with gem rinruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to use rinruby 2.0.3.

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rinruby', '~> 2.0.3'
```

When I execute bundle install, I don't have any problem. But when I execute:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I've got this error:

```
$ rake db:create
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'rinruby'.
/home/jerviver21/workspace_upworkruby/blog1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jerviver21/workspace_upworkruby/blog1/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - R
/home/jerviver21/workspace_upworkruby/blog1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jerviver21/workspace_upworkruby/blog1/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and postgreSQL 9.4.7

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#Buscar en rubygems.org las implementaciones que se necesiten
#Registro y autenticacion de usuarios
gem 'devise'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
#rinruby
gem 'rinruby', '~> 2.0.3'

# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested installing the rinruby 2.0.3 gem on Ruby 2.4.0-dev.

At first , running `require 'rinruby'` gave me an error about not having R installed.

So I followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-r-on-ubuntu-14-04) for installing R on Ubuntu 14.04

After that, the require was successful.

Comment: Thank you!!
That was the problem, it's necesary to have install R, in ubuntu:
Just this:
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev